# Creating a new object from another and reading it from an array. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, inheritance

I have the following example constructor:

```
function Loot(type, sellValue) {
    this.type = type;
    this.sellValue = sellValue; 
}
```

I am looking to inherit these values into other objects, which are then pushed into an array, such as:

```
var inventory = [];

var stone = new Loot("craft", 20);
inventory.push(stone);

var hat = new Loot("clothing", 80);
inventory.push(hat);

var coal = new Loot("ore", 5);
inventory.push(coal);

var diamond = new Loot("ore", 400);
inventory.push(diamond);


console.log(inventory);
```

However, when I do so, my inventory reads as `(Loot, Loot, Loot, Loot)` and not the names given to the items, `(stone, hat, coal, diamond)`.

How can I get around this? I imagine it would require some form of inheritance?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, "*inventory reads as (Loot, Loot, Loot, Loot)*"? How do you output it? And the one you presented consists of only a single item?

Comment: @Bergi Say I have pushed multiple "stone" into the array and console.log(inventory), it returns with [Loot, Loot, Loot, ...].

I have edited the question to better address it, thanks!

Comment: If you have used `console.log`, then `Loot` just shows you that the object was constructed by the `Loot` function. Click on it to expand it and display the properties. Do *not* use an object as suggested in the accepted answer when what you want is an array.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated the question further. If not the previously accepted answer, what would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Well this is a very different question now. But class hierarchies should be avoided unless logically neccessary. It would be easier to add another property to your Loot class like category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when I do so, my inventory reads as `(Loot, Loot, Loot, Loot)` and not the names given to the items, `(stone, hat, coal, diamond)`.

You would need to iterate your `inventory` array and log the `.type` properties of all items:

```
for (var i=0; i<inventory.length; i++)
    console.log(inventory[i].type);
```

Or you'd build right another array from the item types, which could most easily be accomplished with the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var types = inventory.map(function(item) { return item.type; });
console.log(types);
```

Comment: So would you say it's best to add a property to loot called "name" and just add "stone", "hat", etc based on what I'm passing in?

Is the inventory reading them all as "Loot" ideal and not something I should be trying to replace? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Yes, you will need another string property `name`; as @RickLove already wrote your *variable* names have no significance and cannot be programmatically accessed. Also yes, there's nothing wrong with `console.log` showing `Loot` - click on it to see the object! For any actual usage in the program (or output on the screen), you'd iterate the array anyway. Also, for debugging you can try `console.log(JSON.stringify(inventory))` :-)

Answer (score 2):

The variable names like stone do not mean anything to the object. They are a reference to your object, but not the data of the object.

So stone is simply a variable name for the same new Loot that was created.

You have only one Loot object in your example.

Also, if you look in your array with a debugger i will show the type of object (Loot). You need to expand that to see the values inside the object.

Comment: If I wanted it to show up as "stone" in the inventory when using console.log, what would I need to do? I assumed some level of extension or inheritance would be necessary?

Answer (score -1):

The array can not have string keys. 
Apparently you need to use an object to store these objects.

```
function Loot(type, sellValue){
  this.type = type;
  this.sellValue = sellValue; 
}

var inventory = {};
var inventory2 = {};

var stone = new Loot("craft", 20);
var stone1 = new Loot("craft1", 30);
var stone2 = new Loot("craft2", 40);

//or as follows: 
inventory2['stone'] = stone;
inventory2['stone1'] = stone1;
inventory2['stone2'] = stone2;

console.log(inventory);   // Object {craft: Loot, craft1: Loot, craft2: Loot}
console.log(inventory2);  // Object {stone: Loot, stone1: Loot, stone2: Loot}
```

http://jsbin.com/aNiXolo/5/edit

Comment: Interesting. I think I understand. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where did OP use string keys on an array?

Comment: This is not an array. It is an object with multiple named properties that are being accessed by the indexer [] notation rather than the . dot notation.